# Will setTimeout work if the system time is changed

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Wouldn't changing the system time mess up the timers, assigned with the callbacks?
Is the behavior of `setTimeout` the same across all browsers?
And how about `setInterval`? Does all of the stuff about how `setTimeout` works apply to `setInterval`?

Comment: Have you ever tried changing the time in locally to see what happen?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal - yup tried, and it worked without an error, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetTimeout() is independant of the system clock. When you set it, you specify a timespan in ms js takes care of the rest independantly of the system clock.

I'd also imagine that, as js has been around a while now and implemented on all browsers for years that both setTimeout and setInterval would work identically.

I've never had to add browser specific js into my code (until smartphones and 'hover' listeners !)

Comment: Can you post a link or explanation explaining how setTimeout is independent of the system clock?